# Does not contain a definition and no extension method could be found

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin

I am building an android application using C Sharp (with Xamarin) and I am trying to call a method from another class in the current one called FeedActivity.cs but I am getting a rather general error that:

```
"FeedActivity:PostPicture:  Exception of type 'Java.Lang.RuntimeException' was thrown."
```

It is a Java error because Xamarin compiles C# into Java so that it can run on Android.

The code is as follows:

```
#class from which I want to call the method from the FacebookActivity.cs class
public class FeedActivity : BaseActivity
    {

 #the method that actually starts the whole process
 private void PostPicture(pic picture, bool shareOnFacebook) 
    {
       #posts the picture to my own app, no problem here

       #try catch statement, this is where the error comes in
       try
           {
              if (shareOnFacebook) SharePictureOnFacebook(picture);
           }
       catch (Exception ex)
           {
              LogManager.Error(this, ex, "FeedActivity:PostPicture:  ", ex.Message);
           }
    }

 #method from which I want to call the method from the FacebookActivity.cs class
 private void SharePictureOnFacebook(pic picture)
        {
            FacebookActivity permissionAdder = new FacebookActivity();

            #this is the line that is giving me the error
            permissionAdder.AddPermissions()

            #some more code that isn't relevant
        }
     }

#class that I want to use the method from
public class FacebookActivity : BaseActivity
    {
       #method I want to call from FeedActivity.cs in the SharePictureOnFacebook method
       public void AddPermissions() 
       {
          Authorize(this, AdditionalPermissions);
       }
    }
```

UPDATE:

It works when I make it a static method but I need to pass an instance to it for that to work.  Any idea why a static method would work?

Comment: Holy hell Xamarin looks really sweet. I had no idea it existed. Do you like it?

Comment: Yes it is very complete and has basically everything you could need.  It is a little bit of a transition after using Java for Android for a while and sometimes little errors crop up but that is worth the tradeoff to use C# and be able to reuse a lot of code for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code posted this should work. However, I have run into this once before if you have this same class name in a different namespace...and that is the one being used.

Comment: hmm okay no conflict there.  It must be something specific with Xamarin

Comment: it works with a static method, which actually doesn't work with what I need because I need an instance but any idea why that would work?

Comment: I can't think of any reason for this since you are calling it with an instance. Unless that instance is being read as a type?